# How to design a column in crystal report that spans several rows?

Tags: crystal-reports

I'm having a problem with designing a column in crystal report.

What i want to do:

[image]

There are three columns a,b,c. I can design column a and b but unable to design c. How to do it?

Comment: be more specific. When you say "design", are you talking about drawing? or in a cross tab?

Comment: I meant drawing...actually what i was saying the report should be look like that image

Answer (score 0):

You cannot center the value vertically, but it is possible to not draw horizontal lines in column c by using the checkbox named something like "**underlay following sections**". In German it's "**Folgende Bereiche unterlegen**", I don't know the exact wording in English.

For example if your c column contains a group key and a/b columns contain details, you put your c column into the group header checking the `underlay` option. The columns a and b are defined in details section.

The line in the end of your table would be painted in group footer. The horizontal line in a and b column is painted in details section, but only in columns a and b of course.